# Why isn't my CSS animation working?

Tags: html, css

I'm using [this](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) website to help me animate my text by having a 'bounceIn' effect. I looked at the steps and can't figure out why this CSS animation isn't working.

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v479xdg4/5/)
As you can see in the JSFIDDLE linked above I have named the class `bounceIn` like stated in the steps and linked the animation extension in the code. However, nothing is happening.

```
<h1 =class"bounceIn">LIAM DOCHERTY</h1>
<h3 =class"bounceIn">WEB DEVELOPER & GRAPHIC DESIGNER</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the actual animation in your CSS. Additionally, you need to give it a duration. Add this rule:

```
.bounceIn {
    animation: bounceIn 1s; /* Change to whatever desired duration */
}
```

also, fix your class names in your HTML

```
<h1 class="bounceIn">LIAM DOCHERTY</h1>
<h3 class="bounceIn">WEB DEVELOPER & GRAPHIC DESIGNER</h3>
```

You should see your bounce animation work when you run your JSFIDDLE after these fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    <h1 class="bounceIn animated">LIAM DOCHERTY</h1>
    <h3 class="bounceIn animated">WEB DEVELOPER & GRAPHIC DESIGNER</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

the equals sign is on the wrong side:

```
<h1 =class"bounceIn">LIAM DOCHERTY</h1>
```

should be:

```
<h1 class="bounceIn">LIAM DOCHERTY</h1>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing this out. I rectified my mistake. However, the CSS 'bounceIn' animation still doesn't happen.